# Problems with loop/repeat in R

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix, repeat

I need to execute this code many times in order to get 45 different matrices at the end:  `mat[j], j=1:45`. 
Not sure how to use "for-loop" to achieve that, will be grateful for any tips. 
Data files are stored here, year-by-year https://intl-atlas-downloads.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html

```
library(readstata13)  
library(diverse)   
library(plyr)   

for (j in 1:45) {
  dat <- read.dta13(file.choose())

  data = aggregate(dat$export_value, by = list(dat$exporter,dat$commoditycode), FUN = sum)

  colnames(data) = c("land","product","value")  

  dt = split(data, f = data$product)  

  land = as.data.frame(sort(unique(data[, 1])))  

  nds = seq(1, nrow(land), by = 1)  

  texmat = cbind(nds, land)  

  colnames(texmat) = c("num", "land")  

  for (i in 1:length(unique(data[, 2]))) {
    (join(texmat, dt[[i]], by = "land", type = "left")$value)
  }   

  mt = sapply(1:length(unique(data[, 2])), function(i) join(texmat, dt[[i]], by = "land", type = "left")$value)   

  colnames(mt) = unique(data[, 2])   

  rownames(mt) = sort(unique(data[, 1]))   

  mt[is.na(mt)] = 0   

  rcamat=values(mt, category_row = FALSE, norm = "rca",filter = 1, binary = TRUE)   

  rcamat[is.na(rcamat)] = 0   

  tmat = rcamat[rowSums(rcamat) != 0, , drop = TRUE]   

  mat = t(tmat)
}
```

Comment: I would advise you to tag it with the language specific tag to get more specific help - `for-loop` is pretty generic.

Comment: You should also work with indentation in R, and use the common notation to set the round parentheses in the line where the block begins; thus use "for (i in 1:2){"
So, everyone can better read the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're almost there with the for loop. You just need to add 2 concepts:

1) Creating a list of matrices to read at the start. A construction like:

```
filenames <- paste0('H0_',1995:2016,'.dta')
filenames <- c(filenames,paste0('S2_final_',1962:2016,'.dta'))
```

that creates a vector of the files you want to read will allow you to replace `file.choose` with something like the following (inside the loop):

```
dat <- read.dta13(paste0('/path/to/directory/with/files/',filenames[i]))
```

This way you can grab a new file with each loop iteration.

2) Storing the output matrices at the end of the loop. You can do this either by putting them all in a list, or by using `assign` to create a collection of objects. I prefer the list approach:

```
#before the for loop initialize a NULL list:
mats <- NULL
#at the end of the loop, (after mat = t(tmat) but before the close bracket) add this line to add it to the list
mats[[i]] <- mat
```

This will create a list `mats` with `mats[[1]]` holding the first matrix, `mats[[2]]` holding the second, and so on.

You could alternatively create a bunch of objects like so:

```
#at the end of the for loop add
assign(paste0('mat_',i),mat)
```

Which will create `mat_1`, `mat_2`, and so on as separate objects. A full implementation would look something like this:

```
library(readstata13)  
library(diverse)   
library(plyr)   
setwd('/path/to/files/')

filenames <- paste0('H0_',1995:2016,'.dta')
filenames <- c(filenames,paste0('S2_final_',1962:2016,'.dta'))
#you'll have to prune this to the files you actually want, as this list is more than 45

finished_matrices <- NULL
for (j in 1:45) {
  dat <- read.dta13(filenames[i]) #pickup    
  data = aggregate(dat$export_value, by = list(dat$exporter,dat$commoditycode), FUN = sum)
  colnames(data) = c("land","product","value")      
  dt = split(data, f = data$product)      
  land = as.data.frame(sort(unique(data[, 1])))      
  nds = seq(1, nrow(land), by = 1)      
  texmat = cbind(nds, land)     
  colnames(texmat) = c("num", "land")  

  for (i in 1:length(unique(data[, 2]))) {
    (join(texmat, dt[[i]], by = "land", type = "left")$value)
  }   

  mt = sapply(1:length(unique(data[, 2])), function(i) join(texmat, dt[[i]], by = "land", type = "left")$value)    
  colnames(mt) = unique(data[, 2])       
  rownames(mt) = sort(unique(data[, 1]))      
  mt[is.na(mt)] = 0      
  rcamat=values(mt, category_row = FALSE, norm = "rca",filter = 1, binary = TRUE)     
  rcamat[is.na(rcamat)] = 0     
  tmat = rcamat[rowSums(rcamat) != 0, , drop = TRUE]    
  mat = t(tmat)
  finished_matrices[[i]] <- mat
}
```

Comment: Pdubbs, this is absolutely fantastic! works perfectly, thank you very much!

Comment: @IvanLyubimov happy to help! If your problem is solved you should click the check mark to accept the answer :)